# alias_method_chain in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want a module to `alias_method_chain` a method from the class it is included into. Here is how I wrote it:

```
module MyModule
  self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      alias_method_chain :perform, :chain
    end
  end
  def perform_with_chain(opts)
    #Do some stuffs
    perform_without_chain(opts)
    #Do some other stuffs
  end
end

class SomeClass
  include MyModule
  def perform(opts)
  end
end
```

but this throws an error since, when the module is included, the `perform` method is not yet defined in `SomeClass`:

```
in `alias_method': undefined method `perform' for class `SomeClass' (NameError)
```

How should one write this pattern so the alias chain fully works?

Comment: You can write the `include MyModule` at the _end_ of the `SomeClass` declaration...

Answer (score 2):

Include after `perform` is defined.

```
class SomeClass
  def perform(opts)
  end
  include MyModule
end
```

Comment: I don't want to do this since the module could be bundled in a gem, hence it would require that some users be careful as to where to include the module. Any better solution?